# What specific exceptions represent a serialization failure when Django is using serializable transaction isolation level with postgresql?

Tags: django, postgresql, exception, transactions, isolation-level

Sometimes it's desirable to use a higher isolation level than the default "read committed" for database operations in Django.  [The docs warn](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/databases/#isolation-level) that:

> Under higher isolation levels, your application should be prepared to handle exceptions raised on serialization failures.

But which specific exceptions indicate a serialization failure, versus some other problem with the query or transaction?

A simple retry mechanism after a serialization failure might look like something like this:

```
for retries in range(0, 3):
    try:
        with transaction.atomic():
            MyModel.objects.update(foo='bar')
    except StuffHappened:
        continue
    else:
        break
```

What specific exceptions should replace `StuffHappened` so that only serialization failures, and not other exceptions, result in a retry?

Django has a variety of [Database Exceptions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/exceptions/#database-exceptions) and [Transaction Exceptions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/exceptions/#transaction-exceptions).  Might one/some of those represent serialization failures?

I'm specifically interested in postgresql for this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hmm, good question. The documentation implies that the appropriate exception would be a [`TransactionManagementError`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/exceptions/#transactionmanagementerror):

> `TransactionManagementError` is raised for any and all problems related to database transactions.

However, the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.1/django/db/transaction.py#L8) gives a strong clue that it isn't:

```
class TransactionManagementError(ProgrammingError):
    """Transaction management is used improperly."""
    pass
```

Note that this is a [`ProgrammingError`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#programmingerror), which is indeed used to indicate programmer error (i.e. "used improperly").

If we look at the documentation for psycopg (the Python adapter used for PostgreSQL support) we see that it will raise a [`psycopg2.extensions.TransactionRollbackError`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extensions.html#psycopg2.extensions.TransactionRollbackError):

> exception `psycopg2.extensions.TransactionRollbackError` (subclasses `OperationalError`)
>
> Error causing transaction rollback (deadlocks, serialization failures, etc).

But what does Django do with that? Well, as [documented here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/exceptions/#database-exceptions), it wraps the standard Python DB API 2.0 exceptions in Django equivalents, and sets the `__cause__` attribute to the original exception. So the following is probably the most specific check you can make:

```
from django.db import OperationalError
from psycopg2.extensions import TransactionRollbackError

for retries in range(0, 3):
    try:
        with transaction.atomic():
            MyModel.objects.update(foo='bar')
    except OperationalError as e:
        if e.__cause__.__class__ == TransactionRollbackError:
            continue
        else:
            raise            
    else:
        break
```

Depending on the error details exposed by PostgreSQL (available via [`e.__cause__.diag`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extensions.html#psycopg2.extensions.Diagnostics)) it may be possible to write an even more specific test.

Generally, though, the Python DB API 2.0 documentation states that [`OperationalError`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#operationalerror) is indeed the correct exception type for transaction issues, so catching that hopefully would be a reasonably effective database-agnostic solution.